# Sublime Text 2 Highlight Gutter

Tags: text-editor, sublimetext

By default the line number / gutter area in sublime text 2 is highlighted when the caret is on that line. How can I turn it off?

I see options to hide the gutter but I want the line numbers to be visible. Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To turn off line highlighting go to `preferences>settings - User` through the menus and add this line:

```
"highlight_line": false,
```

then save. I am using the default `Monokai` theme in linux, this will change it from:

[image]

to:

[image]

As you can see the line is no longer highlighted (it doesn't show in the picture but my cursor is still on the line), but the gutter numbers are. I think you also want to get rid of that? So, open the theme file `.../sublime-text-2/Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Monokai.tmTheme`, and change the `<key>lineHighlight</key>` colour, so it is the same as the `<key>background</key>` color, ie. `#3E3D32` goes to `#272822`, like this:

[image]
On saving, it should resolve your problem:

[image]

Only the 2nd step is really neccessary.

Comment: @Harry - Cool :) is this for aesthetic reasons, or do you have some deeper need for this??

Comment: I find that changing the color of the gutter draws my attention towards the gutter, which is distracting when trying to code.

Comment: @Harry - ah, I understand, I hate tool tips for that! Accepted answer?

Comment: Interesting. I guess "highlight_line" is false by default. I just turned it on.

Comment: Is it possible in sublime text 3? I can not find theme file on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Some additions

```
"font_size": 9.0,
"caret_style": "smooth",
"highlight_line": true,
"line_padding_bottom": 2,
"line_padding_top": 2,
"fade_fold_buttons": false,
```