# Turn off highlighting gutter in sublime text 3

Tags: editor, sublimetext3

When I turn off line highlight in sublime text 3 gutter is still highlighted

[image: highlighted gutter]

I wish to turn off gutter highlighting but I do not want to hide gutter.

Comment: Possible solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489546/sublime-text-2-highlight-gutter

Comment: @sergioFC I saw this thread but it looks like there is no theme file in sublime text 3 (/Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Monokai.tmTheme). There is some Monokai.tmTheme.cache file instead but it has some numeric data inside.